# .val() will not update content of input box with time

Tags: jquery

The following code produces a ticking clock per the console. The clock is supposed to be displayed in the field `<span class="displayWrapper"><input id="watch" class="column"></span>` via the `display` function. It refuses to do so, and I have never had this problem with the .val() method before. So far as getting things up and running are concerned, my inputs to the `startWatch` function have been 1 and 0, as a positive `breakTime` would cause a lag in execution (at the moment). Any thoughts on a remedy would be appreciated.

```
               function display(deadLine) {
                    let displayDate = new Date(deadLine);
                    let hrs = displayDate.getUTCHours().toString();
                    let min = displayDate.getUTCMinutes().toString();
                    let sec = displayDate.getUTCSeconds().toString();
                    let time = hrs.padStart(2, '0') + ' : ' + min.padStart(2, '0') + " : " + sec.padStart(2, '0');
                    $("#watch").val(time);
                }

                function startWatch(minutes, breakTime) {
                    breakHandler = setTimeout(function() {
                    let initialize = new Date(0);
                    let deadLine = new Date(minutes * 60000);
                    let currDate = Date.now();

                    display(deadLine);

                    tickHandler = setInterval(function() {
                      let timePass = Date.now() - currDate;
                      deadLine = deadLine - timePass;

                      if (deadLine > 0) {
                        let displayDate = new Date(deadLine);

                        display(displayDate);
                        currDate = Date.now();
                        console.log("currDate => " + currDate);
                      } else {
                        clearInterval(tickHandler);
                        startWatch(minutes, breakTime);
                      }
                    }, 1000);
                  }, breakTime);
                }
```

Comment: Validate the value of `time`

Comment: Can't you just do `let displayDate = deadLine;`?

Comment: @Tim -- time looks like this when things are running in the console: 00 : 00 : 44

Comment: @uom-pgregorio -- Correction. Yes, I believe I can make that adjustment, but am unsure of whether or not it will change anything. Will certainly try.

Comment: Aren't you already passing a Date object to the `display` function?

Comment: @uom-pgregorio Made the correction, but updating of input box still a no go.

Comment: Seems to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/vy6ptnmj/44/

Comment: @uom-pgregorio Appreciate you checking. It's seems that I have a bigger problem on my hands then.